# failing to run simple webdriver on pycharm - mac

Tags: python, macos, selenium, firefox, pycharm

I installed pycharm(python3.6) + selenium(3.8) on my mac.

Trying to run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get error:

```
/Users/ronavaida/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python /Users/ronavaida/PycharmProjects/untitled/testselenium.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ronavaida/PycharmProjects/untitled/testselenium.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Users/ronavaida/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 158, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/Users/ronavaida/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/ronavaida/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/ronavaida/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/ronavaida/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: The version of FF you use is probably not matching the version of webdriver that is installed. See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4927

Comment: @Rona Vaida If you solved your current issue do not change exception log in this ticket, but create new ticket regarding your new issue...

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing says it all :

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

You need to download the latest **`geckodriver`** binary from this [**`link`**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)and save it in your system and provide the absolute path of the `geckodriver` binary while initializing the **`WebDriver`** and **`Browser`** instance as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank, but that didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by `that didn't help`? Can you update the question with your current code block and the error stack trace for further analysis?